# replace ". " with "\n\n" within a string in Android

Tags: java, android, replace, special-characters

I try to replace ". " with "\n\n" within a string but it doesnt work, I use the following code:

```
                text=text.replace(". ","\n\n");
```

The result is every word without the last letter of the word in a each line. I read something like the point means any character in this case, but how can I actually refer to the point?

Input Example: "Hello world"
Example of the output:
Hell
world

Thank you

Comment: Try to escape the . symbol by \. I think.

Comment: "every word without the last letter of the word in a each line" <-- non capisco niente... Can you give an example?

Comment: @Lingviston trap... `.replace()` does not use regexes, in spite of its "siblings" `.replaceFirst()` and `.replaceAll()` which do

Comment: "the point means any character in this case" <-- no! `.replace()` does not use regexes... If Android's JDK really does that, it's a bug!

Comment: Or would it be that `text` is not a `String`?

Comment: Does ` text=text.replace("\. ","\n\n");` work?  It looks like you need to escape the '.'

Comment: Again: _`.replace()` does not use regexes!_ See below

Comment: @Raghunandan yup, that seems like the most plausible solution here, I cannot believe Android devs violated `String`

Comment: What is the actual input? How do you know that it did not work as expected?

Answer (score 1):

There is something fishy here; either `text` is not a `String`, or you don't use `.replace()` but something else (`.replaceAll()`?), or Android's `.replace()` is buggy.

And I frankly doubt that Android devs would have had such an overlook.

The [Javadoc for `String#replace()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) says:

> Replaces each substring of this string that matches the **literal target sequence** with the specified **literal replacement sequence.** [emphasis mine]

Unlike its sibling methods (`.replaceFirst()` and `.replaceAll()`) which do use regexes, `.replace()` doesn't (and the fact that internally it does use `Pattern`, at least in Oracle's JDK [*], is not the problem).

Therefore, if you actually use `.replace()` and gain the result you say, this is a bug in Android. If this is the case, try an alternative, like so (UNTESTED):

```
public static String realStringReplace(final String victim, final String target,
    final String replacement)
{

    final int skip = target.length();
    final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(victim.length());

    String tmp = victim;
    int index;

    while (!tmp.isEmpty()) {
        index = tmp.indexOf(target);
        if (index == -1)
            break;
        sb.append(tmp.subString(0, index)).append(replacement);
        tmp = tmp.subString(index + skip);
    }

    return sb.append(tmp).toString();
}
```

Comment: There is ZERO probability of a bug that major still existing in the Android code-base.  In fact, almost ZERO probability that it ever existed in the first place.

Comment: @StephenC I agree; then what?

Comment: It is a bug in the Question.  Either he's given us the wrong code, or it doesn't behave how he thinks/claims it does.  Most likely the former.

Answer (score 0):

the point means any character if you use

```
text=text.replaceAll(". ", "\n\n");
```

perhaps you have posted the wrong code, in this case try this one:

```
text=text.replaceAll("\\. ", "\n\n");
```

the strange thing is that this line is equivalent to the line that you have posted..